# Ajax WaterMark Extender

Tags: c#, ajax

Whenever I attempt to set text on the WaterMark Extender (which is on a control) dynamically I get an error saying the that **TextBoxWatermarkExtendor missing required watermarktext property value for textboxWatermarkExtender1**. The problem is I ONLY get this error some of the time on some computers. It seems to be a loading issue and not browser specific. Does anyone know where I can get some more info about this?

Answer (score 0):

You may not be actually setting the property for watermarktext for the extender.

Take a look @ this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtWatermark" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>

 <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtWatermark_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" runat="server"

  Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtWatermark" WatermarkText="Type Your Search Here">

 </cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
```

But it is strange that it works only in some computers. Make sure Javascript is turned on in the browsers.

[This website](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1717-ajax-extenders-for-textbox-tutorial.aspx) has a great tutorial on Watermarked Textboxes + much more :)